# Entity Framework - convert field as enum

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, enums, entity-framework-6

I have the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Decisions](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [DecisionName] [nvarchar](250) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Decisions] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Vacancies](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [DecisionID] [int] NOT NULL,
    .....
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Vacancies] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Vacancies]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Vacancies_Decisions] FOREIGN KEY([DecisionID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Decisions] ([ID])
ON UPDATE CASCADE
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Vacancies] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Vacancies_Decisions]
GO
```

so, as you can see, Decisions and Vacancies linked between each other as one-to-many.
Ok. Then I create an ADO.NET Entity Data Model in my .NET application and then try to convert ID for Decision to enum. Completed. Then I try to compile my application and get the following error:

> Error 2   Error 112: The types of all properties in the Dependent Role
>   of a referential constraint must be the same as the corresponding
>   property types in the Principal Role. The type of property
>   'DecisionID' on entity 'VTSModel.Vacancy' does not match the type of
>   property 'ID' on entity 'VTSModel.Decision' in the referential
>   constraint 'FK_Vacancies_Decisions'.

Why it happens? I have 4 records in Decision table (with ID equials 1, 2, 3, 4), created 4 enum values with such ids, Underlying type is Int32, table Vacancies is empty at all (field DecisionID of Vacancy entity has Int32 too)

I use Visual Studio 2013 + MVC 5 + Entity Framework 6.1.2 + MS SQL 2014

Comment: Not really related to your question, but why do you have a table that contains only a natural key and a surrogate key? If there are no other attributes to a `Decision` other than its name, then there's no reason to have a separate table.

Comment: And to answer the question, `enum` is implemented in the CLR as an `int32`, but it is not an `int32`. It is a separate type, so you cannot - in the EF world - use it to reference an `int32` in the other entity.

Comment: @Keith Payne do you propose me to use string like "This is a decision bla-bla-bla" instead of ID in other tables? And always check if this string is the same, but not "this is a decision bla-bla-bla" (from lowercase letter) for example?

Comment: @Keith Payne have I to change DecisionID in Vacancy to enum type too?

Comment: Yes, you would change the ID to the same enum type to make it work.